# saving to tif bloats image

Tags: .net, bitmap, compression, tiff

I have a list of 6 bitmap images, that each one by itself if I save it as .png files, they take about 200-300 KB of disk space.

When I save them to a single .tif, though, they explode to about a 10 MB tif file.

Setting the quality parameter to 10 (which is very very low I think), brings it down to 9.5, still a far cry from the approxiamte 1.5 MB it should be.

The images are mostly color scanned documents (32bpp)

Here is the code:

```
Function ImagesTif(Images As IEnumerable(Of Image)) As MemoryStream
        Dim tif = Images(0)
        Dim stmTiff = New MemoryStream
        Dim encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders.First(Function(i) i.MimeType = "image/tiff")
        Dim tifParams = New EncoderParameters(2)
        Dim prmCompress = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 10)
        tifParams.Param(0) = prmCompress
        tifParams.Param(1) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, EncoderValue.MultiFrame)
        tif.Save(stmTiff, encoderInfo, tifParams)
        Dim imgParams = New EncoderParameters(2)
        imgParams.Param(0) = prmCompress
        imgParams.Param(1) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage)
        For Each img In Images.Skip(1)
            tif.SaveAdd(img, imgParams)
        Next
        Dim endParams = New EncoderParameters(1)
        endParams.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, EncoderValue.Flush)
        tif.SaveAdd(endParams)
        Return stmTiff
End Function
```

Please advise

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Originally I was using LZW compression, but since it was giving me 10MB files, I tried the `Quality` compression. Here is the original (LZW) code:

```
Dim encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders.First(Function(i) i.MimeType = "image/tiff")
Dim tifParams = New EncoderParameters(2)
Dim cmprs = EncoderValue.CompressionLZW
Dim prmCompress = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, cmprs)
```

All the rest is identical to code above.

So far, neither is giving the expected result.

**UPDATE 2**

Following suggestions from @haraldK, I found some code that can compress with `zip` compression.

So this is my new code:

```
Function ImagesTif(Images As IEnumerable(Of Image)) As MemoryStream
        Dim stream = New MemoryStream 'As New FileStream("new.tif", FileMode.Create)
        Dim encoder As New System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffBitmapEncoder()
        encoder.Compression = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffCompressOption.Zip
        For Each img In Images
            Dim strmBmap = img.AsBitmap.ToStream 'a helper function to turn a bitmap into a stream
            strmBmap.Position = 0
            encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(strmBmap))
        Next
        encoder.Save(stream)
        Return stream
    End Function
```

But this code too, gives a 9.8 MB file, instead of approxiamtely 1.5 MB.

What gives?

Comment: "Quality" doesn't mean much for TIFF compression, as it's (usually) lossless. However, TIFF supports many compression algorithms. It seems you end up with uncompressed files. Try specifying Zip/Deflate or LZW compression with predictor, and you should get close to the PNG sizes.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your input. I had originally tried LZW, but it was not working (please see my added code to the post). Where can i find sample code for zip/deflate? It does not seem to appear in the list of encoder values.

Comment: Any ideas anybody? I'm really stuck here without any good way to save jpgs as a `tif` file. I need it for scanned images, or just plain concentrating multiple images to one document. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably tag your question with a programming language tag. As the problem seems to be related to the library you use (I'm a Java developer, so I can't help you here). A TIFF stored using LZW should be comparable in size to a PNG. Zip/Deflate may be even closer,  but PNG has better predictor options so they won't be exactly the same. But of course, none of this helps if the library doesn't support it or doesn't work.

Comment: Hi. I added the `.net` tag as well as some new code that i found. No luck.